# When pushing a file in my repository using VScode the author isn't me but another user

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to push into my repository but for some reason every time I tried to do it the commit is made by another user. To be honest I'm not sure if that user is mine too (maybe? Probably I can't remember). Nevertheless I'm logged in my account, (on vscode) I even delete all credentials in the Credential Manager in Windows.

Below you can see I'm logged into my account. (Sharkics)

[image]

I commit locally with control+enter, then I go the menu and push it. But when I go to my repository the author from that push isn't me.

[image]

These are the steps to make this happening.

1. I create a repository in GitHub manually.
2. I copy the url from the respository.
3. I clone it in vscode. (Shift + P, clone it, and paste the url)
4. Select the folder I'll use.
5. Create a file, not matter what, for example a react project.
6. I commit this locally.
7. I push it.

What's happening? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `git config -l` in a terminal in your project folder. It should show settings for user.email and user.name.

I guess those are not correct and you can update them either by editing the local, system or global git config. i.e.

```
git config --local user.email "me@example.com"
git config --local user.name "Omar "
```

For changes in the local repository only. Change to system or global depending on your needs

Comment: Is xSecurityLabs supposed to show up there? Because `user.name` only contains my nickname, Sharki. I've updated the post with a picture showing what appears after using that command, but the name and email look fine

Comment: Can I assume that this other account does not have the same email address?
Do you also have the same issue if commiting from the terminal? My guess is that VSCode has some git config internally as well so you should get the correct user in terminal.

Comment: check out the note under https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-support 
It seems there is a git config in VSCode as well :/

Comment: I just noticed that my email wasn't the same (I was pretty sure it was) and for some reason it was using the account linked to that email. (Which is kinda weird because I was using the tokens from the right one, but pushing/commiting as the second account, does it mean I can push as every user as long as I know their email? I don't think so, pretty sure it's saving credentials somewhere lol) anyway I've changed the email and it works, thanks! :)

Comment: Tokens for authentication/credentials do not need to match user.email in the config and are used for completely different things. This leads to some confusion with certain tools (like VSCode) but you need to remember that a token might not be connected to an email (even though it usually is).

Summary:
- user.email/user.name in git config are used in commit message
- tokens are use to authorize access to the server and has nothing to do with git itself

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands :

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you need to set a default account, you can simply set the following Git configuration:

`git config --global credential.< URL >.username  < USERNAME >`

..where `<URL>` is the remote URL and `<USERNAME>` is the account you wish to have as the default. For example, for github.com and the user alice:

`git config --global credential.https://xxxxxxgithub.com/xxxx.git.username alice`